# elf processing by linkers(both dynamic and program)

Tags: linker, loader, elf

I am working on a project that involves ELF binary file parsing. From past few weeks I am reading quite a bit on ELF format.
However, one thing I really want to understand is how linkers and loaders use the different sections in an ELF file. Can someone please suggest me some resources which can teach me about the same.  Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

A detailed description of how an ELF linker works by the author of [GNU gold](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gold_%28linker%29) can be found in a series of blog posts starting [here](http://www.airs.com/blog/archives/38).

(Runtime) loaders do not use any sections of the ELF files (a valid `ET_DYN` or `ET_EXEC` ELF file can have all section headers stripped). They only use *segments*. I don't know of any good description of an ELF loader, but [here](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/6463) is a possible start.